# There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Tabs'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables

Table #1:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabs
(
    TabId int,
    UserId int,
    TabName varchar(20),
    SettingName varchar(5000), 

    PRIMARY KEY (TabId, userId),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES UserProfile(UserId),
)
```

Table #2:

```
CREATE TABLE TabsSettings
(
    TabId int,
    UserId int,
    TabName varchar(20),
    SettingName varchar(5000),
    SettingValue varchar(5000),
    ModifiedOn datetime,
    CreatedOn datetime,

    PRIMARY KEY (TabId, userId),
    FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES Tabs(UserId),
    FOREIGN KEY (TabId) REFERENCES Tabs(TabIdId) 
)
```

When I am trying to execute my 2nd query it shows this error

> Msg 1776, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Tabs' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key 'FK_*TabsSetti*_UserI__7EF6D905'.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: in the first table command you are using a column from UserProfile, which must exist before creating Tabs table, so for first table creation you need an already created table UserProfile having UserId column

Also in the 2nd creation command, you are indicating TabIdId
this column is not there in Tabs table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reference *both* columns with a *single* foreign key:

```
 FOREIGN KEY (TabId,UserId) REFERENCES Tabs(TabId,UserId)
```

Comment: ya checked that and got it. Thanks anyways